# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table My_Table not found inserting data via PSQL in Apache Phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm in the process to load a bulk data via PSQL (psql.py) in Apache Phoenix, but for some reason is throwing me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table "My_Table" not found
at org.apache.phoenix.util.SchemaUtil.generateColumnInfo(SchemaUtil.java:887)
at org.apache.phoenix.util.CSVCommonsLoader.buildColumnInfoList(CSVCommonsLoader.java:259)
at org.apache.phoenix.util.CSVCommonsLoader.upsert(CSVCommonsLoader.java:206)
at org.apache.phoenix.util.CSVCommonsLoader.upsert(CSVCommonsLoader.java:182)
at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixRuntime.main(PhoenixRuntime.java:273)
```

According to Phoenix tutorial https://phoenix.apache.org/Phoenix-in-15-minutes-or-less.html I need to have 3 files; `my_table.sql` `my_table.csv` and `my_table_queries.sql`

and launch the following command:

```
 ./psql.py <your_zookeeper_quorum> my_table.sql my_table.csv my_table_queries.sql
```

The content of those files are as follow:

my_table.sql

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "some_namespace:my_table" (id BIGINT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, username));
```

my_table.csv

```
 1,Martha
 2,Scott
 3,David
 4,Alex
 5,Vicky
```

my_table_queries.sql

```
 SELECT id as "ID's", username as "User Name"
 FROM "some_namespace:my_table"
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY count(username) DESC;
```

And when I access Phoenix via sqlline.py the table is there, but with no data at all. Should I create the table first or in a different way?

Comment: `some_namespace:my_table` in the `CREATE TABLE` does not match `"some_spacename:my_table"` in your `SELECT`. **namespace** is not the same as **spacename**.

Comment: That was a typo, I already correct it, the problem remains

Comment: Then [edit] your question and include your actual code by copy/pasting it, instead of typing it in where you can introduce additional problems. If you want help with your code, **post your actual code**.

Answer (score 1):

IT seems that the table names are case sensitive in Phoenix. Since you have enclosed a double quote when creating the table, just pass the same when running the bulk load job.

my_table.sql

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MY_TABLE" (id BIGINT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, username));
```

my_table_queries.sql:

```
 SELECT id as "ID's", username as "User Name"
 FROM "MY_TABLE"
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY count(username) DESC;
```

This was already reported: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-3541?attachmentSortBy=dateTime

Also you can check the explanation about the case sensitive http://apache-phoenix-user-list.1124778.n5.nabble.com/Load-into-Phoenix-table-via-CsvBulkLoadTool-cannot-find-table-and-fails-td2792.html

Now, if you want to load bulk data into HBASE using .csv files you can try this: http://dwgeek.com/apache-hbase-bulk-load-csv-examples.html/

Comment: It make sense in a way, but the error still there, Here is the thing, I can create tables under the namespaces only, for security matters,  and the namespaces are fixed I cannot do something like `"some_namespace:MY_TABLE"` because does't work, so I don't know what else  to do.